# Нужно поправить дату и время создания папок (директорий) в Windows-10

Tags: windows, файлы, администрирование, windows-10

Есть в Windows-10 утилита  touch, запускаемая из командной строки. Она умеет менять дату и время для файлов.

Нужна такая же утилита (тоже запускаемая из командной строки), которая умеет менять дату и время для папок (директорий).

Подскажите куда копать. Не писать же самому такую утилиту.

[зачем изменять дату создания] Объясняю. В батнике создается блок директорий с файлами, далее это блок зипуется и отправляется заказчику. Нужно, чтобы все файлы и все директории в зипе были одной даты и времени для данного зипа. Так заказчик может отличить версии и даты поставки версий (дополнительно к собственно номеру версии).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77991/discussion-on-question-by-pepsicoca1-------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так решение уже существует:
[touch(batch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249233/how-do-i-touch-a-file-with-standard-windows-commands)

Соответственно, достаточно 1-ой команды:

```
forfiles /p c:\Directory /s /m * /c "cmd /c @copy @path /B+ ,,/Y"
```

Недостаток команды проявляется при большом количестве файлов (несколько тысяч) и медленной работе системы - расхождение во времени изменения файлов может составить до нескольких секунд.
Основной же минус - атрибуты каталогов не обрабатываются.  Но это уже мелочи и "допиливается", например, следующей командой:

```
powershell -command Write-Output "(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Directory -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }) | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime=(get-Date '16.12.2014 00:00')}"
```